# What element type would be best if I want to achieve custom text styles and accept multiline string text without truncating spaces displayed?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I am creating a program that will take an uploaded text file, read its text and highlight certain things (through injecting `<span>` with specific classes) into the file and display on a webpage. What I am having trouble with is how I can show these results.

I was initially using `<textarea>`, but I found that apparently, it does not recognize those `<span>` tags I have injected, so it just displayed as plain text. I tried using other approaches like `<p>` or `<span>` or `<article>` but it seems that all of those other ones will either

- remove spaces accordingly (the text file uses a ton of spaces to format the text too and that needs to be retained), or
- it will not recognize multi-line strings

So, some may suggest that perhaps I can simply inject a `<br/>` tag at all line breaks, which is a viable option for sure. The problem with the spaces that are truncated still remains if I do that. Not to mention that the 
 tags will mess up a lot of my `<span>` formatting injection that I was trying to do, which relies on regex currently but that's at least doable.

What would be the best way to overcome this problem? Is there an obscure tag that will work best for the purpose here? Or what you be my best course moving forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `<div>` and convert all the space characters to `&nbsp;` if you really want to retain them (although it kind of goes against the way HTML is intended to work, but it's up to you).

And and all the newline characters need to be converted to `<br/>`  - again the way HTML does layout is completely different to how a text file does it.

Comment: Well, the purpose of the tool was to mark up a text file. So, yea... I was thinking textarea is perfect initially until the spans were not recognized. I guess if that's the way, then I'll write a conversion function then. Thanks!